# Change Styling for WinUI3 TreeView Items On State

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, datatemplate, winui-3

I am trying to get a TreeView to look kind of "grayed out" and disable the use of it on a boolean being true. The issue I am having is the current layout of the XAML seems to be preventing this and I am having a hard time finding a way around it.

This is the layout of the XAML I'm using and am not sure how/if I can pass the Parent's DataContext down into the DataTemplate:

```
<Grid>
 <TreeView>
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:DataType="ViewModelObject">
    <TreeViewItem ItemSource="{x:Bind Children" Content="{x:Bind Name}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
 </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

What I would like to do is to add a field of `Foreground` to the TreeViewItem to change the color based off a variable in the ViewModel, but the DataTemplate having a separate DataContext is preventing this.

If there are other ways to make it have that "grayed out" disabled look, I would also love advice there, this is just the best way I came up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `{Binding}` instead of `{x:Bind}`, that will let you use the `ElementName` property to get the page (give it an `x:Name` first) and from there you can navigate to your `ViewModel` property and to whatever you need out of it.

Comment: Also make up your mind what you're using, the above is for WinUI3. If you want WPF you're already using `{Binding}` so it's nothing special.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Never had needed to bind to another Element before. Makes perfect sense now

Comment: It's pretty common, especially for things like master-detail views where you select one item from the master list and that populates the detail list accordingly.  Or in this case, binding outside of your data context.